# aspx bind data with '#' symbol to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Been trying to fix this for hours and I know that the problem is with the '#' but I could not find any solution to this problem. My field name in the database is 'HRTRN#'.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction#">
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HRTRN#") %>'   Width="50px" Height="17px" MaxLength="14"></asp:TextBox>
   </EditItemTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HRTRN#") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Does anyone know the solution for this to make the field name containing # symbol accessible?

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code from :

`Bind("HRTRN#")`

To

`Bind("[HRTRN#]")`

Since it contains special charcters. ( you would do that also for columns with spaces).